# Is the function characterized by $f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y) \le f^{\alpha}(\alpha x)f^{1-\alpha}(y)$ convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Is a non-negative function $f(x)$ convex ? If for $x  \ge y$ it satisfies for any $\alpha \in [0,1]$.
\begin{align}
f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y) \le f^{\alpha}(\alpha x)f^{1-\alpha}(y)  \ \text{       eq.1}
\end{align}

This is very reminiscent of the log-convexity which is defined as
\begin{align}
f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y) \le f^{\alpha}( x)f^{1-\alpha}(y).
\end{align}

**Extra Hypothesis we can add:**

1. There exist a log-convex function $g(x)$ such that $f(x) \le g(x)$ and such that
   \begin{align} f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha) y)  \le
       g^\alpha(x)f^{1-\alpha}(y). \end{align}
2. $f(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$.

**A little back ground:**
I am trying to show that if $f$ satisfies eq.$1$ then it is **continuous**.  The property that came to my mind is that if $f$ is convex then it is continuos on the open set. The condition in eq.$1$ is very similar to log-convexity (recall log-convexity implies convexity) and the hope is that it implies convexity.

Thank you for any help and suggestions, in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Note. This is an edited answer based on the helpful discussions with OP, as shown in the comments.]

Thanks for the interesting question.  Here are some of my observations, and please let me know if I did something wrong.  Thanks.

#### Observation 1

With $x = y$, we have from eq. 1,
$$
f(y) \le f^{\alpha}(\alpha y) \, f^{1-\alpha}(y).
$$
Since $f(y)$ is nonnegative,
$$
f(y) \le f(\alpha y).  \qquad (1)
$$
This means the function $f(y)$ is decreasing for $y \ge 0$ and increasing for $y \le 0$.

A corollary is that
$$
f(x) \le f(0).  \qquad (2)
$$

#### Observation 2

Let $y < 0$ and $\alpha x = (1 - \alpha) (-y) > 0$, we have
$$
f(0) \le f^{\alpha}(\alpha x)\, f^{1-\alpha}(y).
$$
But by (2) we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(\alpha x) &\le f(0), \\
f(y) &\le f(0).
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
f(0) \le f^{\alpha}(\alpha x)\, f^{1-\alpha}(y) \le f(0).
$$
This is possible only if both $f(\alpha x)$ and $f(y)$ are equal to $f(0)$.
In other words, $f(x)$ is a constant.

#### Observation 3

The above argument shows that eq. 1 is a very stringent condition on $f$, if $y$ can take any real number.  However, if we impose the restriction $y \ge 0$, any monotonically decreasing function satisfies the requirement, eq. 1.  This is because
$$
\begin{align}
f(y) &\ge f(y + \alpha \, (x-y)), \\
f(\alpha x) &\ge f(\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) \, y),
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
f^{1-\alpha}(y)f^\alpha(\alpha x) \ge f(\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y).
$$

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you very insightful. Do you see anyway of dropping the assumption of moronically decreasing function? For example, can we do anything with extra hypothesis 1.

Comment: You're welcome. I actually have a question about the extra hypothesis 1. If $g(x)$ or $f(x)$ log-convex?

Comment: If $y \ge 0$, then the hypothesis of $f(y)$ being decreasing is implied by eq. 1: if we plug $x = y$ into eq. 1, then $f(y) \le f^\alpha(\alpha y) f^{1-\alpha}(y)$, which means $f(y) \le f(\alpha y)$, for $0 < \alpha < 1$, then $f(x)$ has to be decreasing for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: $g(x) $ is log-convex. I will correct the questions. Thanks

Comment: @Boby. Thanks, I updated the answer.  It seems that eq. 1 alone implies that $f(x)$ is a constant, if I were correct in observation 2.  Do you see any mistakes in the argument?  Or should we replace eq. 1 with something less stringent?  Thanks.

Comment: No, I don't see any wrong with you reasoning. Great intuition. Now that I started thinking about I actually wanted to study: $ f( \alpha x+(1-\alpha) y)  \le f^\alpha \left( \frac{x}{\alpha} \right) f^{1-\alpha}(y)$. I think this a more interesting question. What do you think.?

Comment: @Boby.  The variant is indeed harder! :-)

Comment: @hpb do you think it's worth posting it as new question? By the way you will get the bounty for this question for sure.

Comment: @Boby.  How about me posting the question for you, if you don't mind?

Comment: Sure,  go ahead.

Comment: @Boby. Hi, I asked the question here, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509887/  Maybe you can answer it for me this time :-)  About the bounty, I'd like to waiver it, if possible.  I am quite happy about my current reputation level, and kind of like to keep it that way :-).  Thanks for the interesting question and guiding me through the solution!

Comment: Hey, are you sure you don't want the bounty? The 50 points are just going to get waisted.

Comment: @Boby. Second thought.  I think I can use the bounty to fund the follow up question, how about that?  Thank you very much for your generosity!